# Printer prints first page value in all pages using local report in rdlc

Tags: c#, rdlc, localreport

I have designed the bill using rdlc report.In that report, i am using without preview to print. It is based on this link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252091.aspx.

It generates bills with 20 rows perfectly.In case table rows goes to above 20 records in table, same first page generates again next page.I searched a lot of things in google..But i am unable to find the proper solution.I am so tired.

```
namespace Hotel_Project
{
public class PrintClassNew : IDisposable
{
    int Paper_height = 0;
    private int m_currentPageIndex;
    private IList<Stream> m_streams;
    //int 
    // Routine to provide to the report renderer, in order to
    //    save an image for each page of the report.
    private Stream CreateStream(string name, string fileNameExtension, Encoding encoding, string mimeType, bool willSeek)
    {
        Stream stream = new MemoryStream();
        m_streams.Add(stream);
        return stream;
    }
    // Export the given report as an EMF (Enhanced Metafile) file.
    private void Export(LocalReport report)
    {
        string deviceInfo =
          @"<DeviceInfo><OutputFormat>EMF</OutputFormat><StartPage>0</StartPage><PageWidth>3.5in</PageWidth><PageHeight>8.1in</PageHeight><MarginTop>0in</MarginTop><MarginLeft>0in</MarginLeft><MarginRight>0in</MarginRight><MarginBottom>0in</MarginBottom></DeviceInfo>";
        Warning[] warnings;
        m_streams = new List<Stream>();
        report.Render("Image", deviceInfo, CreateStream,
           out warnings);
        foreach (Stream stream in m_streams)
            stream.Position = 0;
    }
    // Handler for PrintPageEvents
    private void PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs ev)
    {
        Metafile pageImage = new
           Metafile(m_streams[m_currentPageIndex]);

        // Adjust rectangular area with printer margins.
        Rectangle adjustedRect = new Rectangle(
            ev.PageBounds.Left - (int)ev.PageSettings.HardMarginX,
            ev.PageBounds.Top - (int)ev.PageSettings.HardMarginY,
            ev.PageBounds.Width,
            ev.PageBounds.Height);

        // Draw a white background for the report
        ev.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, adjustedRect);

        // Draw the report content
        ev.Graphics.DrawImage(pageImage, adjustedRect);

        // Prepare for the next page. Make sure we haven't hit the end.
        m_currentPageIndex++;
        ev.HasMorePages = (m_currentPageIndex < m_streams.Count);
    }

    private void Run(DataTable dt)
    {
        LocalReport report = new LocalReport();
        report.ReportPath = "Report.rdlc";
        report.DataSources.Add(
           new ReportDataSource("BillReport", dt));

        ReportParameter[] param = new ReportParameter[18];
            param[0] = new ReportParameter("hotelname", label4.Text, true);
            param[1] = new ReportParameter("hoteladdress", TempPrint_Address, true);
            param[2] = new ReportParameter("gstno", Temp_Print_GSTNo, true);
            param[3] = new ReportParameter("printmessage", Temp_Print_OutMessage, true);
            param[4] = new ReportParameter("companyname", sql.ReadSetting("BillBy"), true);
            param[5] = new ReportParameter("billno", label7.Text, true);
            param[6] = new ReportParameter("billdate", label8.Text, true);
            param[7] = new ReportParameter("billtime", DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss tt"), true);
            param[8] = new ReportParameter("billtype", BookingType, true);
            param[9] = new ReportParameter("billmode", PayMode, true);
            param[10] = new ReportParameter("billamount", " RS " + Convert.ToString(Temp_Amount) + " /-", true);
            param[11] = new ReportParameter("total", Convert.ToString(Temp_Amount), true);
            param[12] = new ReportParameter("qty", Convert.ToString(Temp_QtyNew), true);
            param[13] = new ReportParameter("sgst", Convert.ToString(Temp_GST), true);
            param[14] = new ReportParameter("cgst", Convert.ToString(Temp_GST), true);
            param[15] = new ReportParameter("autual", Convert.ToString(Temp_Amount - Temp_TotalTAXAmount), true);
            if (Temp_TotalTAXAmount == 0)
                param[16] = new ReportParameter("Temp_TotalTAXAmount", Convert.ToString(Temp_TotalTAXAmount), true);
            else
                param[16] = new ReportParameter("Temp_TotalTAXAmount", Convert.ToString(Temp_TotalTAXAmount / 2), true);
            param[17] = new ReportParameter("TotalGst", Convert.ToString(Temp_GST + Temp_GST), true);

            //LocalReport.ReportPath = "BillPrint.rdlc";

            report.SetParameters(param);
            report.Refresh();
        Export(report);
        Print();
    }

    private void Print()
    {
        if (m_streams == null || m_streams.Count == 0)
            throw new Exception("Error: no stream to print.");
        PrintDocument printDoc = new PrintDocument();
        if (!printDoc.PrinterSettings.IsValid)
        {
            throw new Exception("Error: cannot find the default printer.");
        }
        else
        {
            //printDoc.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Top = 0;
            //printDoc.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Bottom = 0;
            //printDoc.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Left = 0;
            //printDoc.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Right = 0;
            printDoc.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = new PaperSize("", 300, (370 + Paper_height));

            printDoc.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(PrintPage);
            m_currentPageIndex = 0;
            printDoc.Print();
            Paper_height = 0;
        }
    }
    // Create a local report for Report.rdlc, load the data,
    //    export the report to an .emf file, and print it.
    public void Run(LocalReport report, int Print_height)
    {
        Paper_height = Print_height;
        // LocalReport report = new LocalReport();
        //report.ReportPath = @"D:\Sathish\FreeLance\Projects\testing_PrintConsole\testing_PrintConsole\Report.rdlc";
        //string[] sqlparArrNew1 = { };
        //DataSet dsNew = GetDataSetFromSP("USP_test", sqlparArrNew1, 2);

        //report.DataSources.Add(
        //   new ReportDataSource("DataSet1", dsNew.Tables[0]));
        Export(report);
        Print();
        Dispose();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (m_streams != null)
        {
            foreach (Stream stream in m_streams)
                stream.Close();
            m_streams = null;
        }
    }

    private static SqlConnection Get_connection(int Con_Status)
    {
        string Connection_Name = "";
        if (Con_Status == 1) { Connection_Name = "Testing_con"; }
        else if (Con_Status == 2) { Connection_Name = "ExcelTrack"; }
        SqlConnection con1 = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[Connection_Name].ConnectionString);

        return con1;
    }
    public DataSet GetDataSetFromSP(string procedureName, string[] parametervalues, int con_status)
    {
        SqlConnection sqlcon = Get_connection(con_status);

        DataSet resultTable = new DataSet();
        //  WriteLog("Query Execution starts....");
        try
        {
            SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand(procedureName, sqlcon);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(procedureName, sqlcon);
            //  WriteLog("Query : " + procedureName);
            sqlcmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            if (sqlcon.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            { sqlcon.Open(); }

            SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlcmd);
            SqlCommandBuilder.DeriveParameters(cmd);

            int i = 0;

            foreach (SqlParameter p in cmd.Parameters)
            {
                if (p.Direction == ParameterDirection.Input)
                {
                    //if (parametervalues[i].Trim() == string.Empty)
                    //    sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(p.ParameterName, DBNull.Value);
                    //else
                    sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(p.ParameterName, parametervalues[i]);
                    //    WriteLog("Parameter: " + p.ParameterName + " | " + parametervalues[i]);
                    i++;
                }
            }

            adp.Fill(resultTable);
            //   WriteLog("Query Execution End....");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (sqlcon.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                sqlcon.Close();
            }
            sqlcon = null;
        }

        return resultTable;
    }
}
}
```

> My bill samples bellow,

[image]
Thanks advance!

Comment: It is hard to say why this is happening if you do not provide us any line of code.

Comment: I have updated code.Pls check.

Comment: Every report shows multiple bills or does every report simply does retrieve one bill? At every Print() call you always set the m_currentPageIndex = 0; - so perhaps this is your problem?

Comment: When i generate new bill,the first page with full body prints in all pages.

Comment: It generates bills with 20 rows perfectly.In case table rows goes to above 20 records in table, same first page generates again next page

Comment: I think it has something todo with m_currentPageIndex = 0; variable. Please verify with debugging that it does really increase and that you get different data for each page. Perhaps your data is always filled with the first page bill data?

Comment: Yes it changed one by one.

Comment: Beased on this condition, it prints same value one by one.                 
        m_currentPageIndex++;
        ev.HasMorePages = (m_currentPageIndex < m_streams.Count);

Comment: So if this is working the Stream does always contain the same data of the first page. Please check your report and the stream creation methods regarding this problem.

Comment: Ok. i will cross check and update to you.

Comment: ok.Is there any way to change memory stream add? and how to check what steam inserted before?

Comment: I have checked stream list .It contains different steam.with out printer , it saved as 2 pages correctly.but when I click print button,,same first pages printing in all pages.

Comment: So did it ever run, with the original unmodified example? Anothe rpossibility is that you retrieve the wrong data. I sadly cannot reproduce here due to lack of project and data : (